# How can I call a HTTPS soap web service in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I am trying to create an android application in which I am calling a HTTPS server.
I know how to call HTTP, but I am unable to call HTTPS server. My code is shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinner;
    Button send;
    EditText number, comments;
    String dropdown;
    TextView feedbackText;
    private static final String[] paths = {"About Test Center", "About Mobile App"};

    final private static String URL = "https://122.180.25.2/TempWS/WebServices/WebService1.asmx";
    final private static String METHOD_NAME = "RegisterComplaint";
    final private static String NAMESPACE = "https://122.180.25.2/";
    final private static String SOAP_ACTION = "https://122.180.25.2/RegisterComplaint";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Feedback");
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        comments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        feedbackText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AsyncFeedback().execute();
            }
        });
    }

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            dropdown = "About Test Center";
            break;
        case 1:
            dropdown = "About Mobile App";
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}

public class AsyncFeedback extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String resp;
    String Number = number.getText().toString();
    String Comments = comments.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            //request.addProperty("topic",dropdown);
            request.addProperty("sender", Number);
            request.addProperty("topic", dropdown);
            request.addProperty("CompDetails", Comments);
            //request.addProperty("details",Comments);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            try {
                HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                resp = result.toString();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resp;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dropdown = null;
        number.setText("");
        comments.setText("");
        feedbackText.setText(result);
    }
}
}
```

The logcat is shown below:

[Click here to view the image of logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH3AZ.png)

Any help would be appreciated. I want to make this code work(how to call HTTPS). Thank You!!

Comment: You need to know the SSLCertificate if it is changing once in a while otherwise you can bypass it using X509TrustManager and SSLContext to trust all certificates.

Comment: @Mike How can I do that? I am new in this stuff.

Comment: Wait I can share you my answer but it is something done with REST not SOAP

Comment: @Mike Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Nair123 just try removing https and call it like a normal server by writing only http. if your service file is in httpdocs folder(i.e. the same folder where index.html is) then you wont have to write https. either try removing 's' from https or try shifting your service to httpdocs folder.you can have your webService.cs file whereever you want but webService.asmx(which will have path to the .cs file) should be there in httpdocs folder only. Anything inside httpdocs can be accessed directly without password

Comment: @KunalParikh I cannot do that the network here in my place is in https. It cannot be done in http.

Comment: @Nair123 then post the logcat for errors. i will look into it

Comment: @KunalParikh I have added the image above. Please check.